# How to parse datetime without date in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

If I have a string like `15:00` and I parse this to `DateTime` ot `DateTimeOffset`, the date is set to today.

I want somehow to distinguish, if the date part is given or not. It would help, if the date part is not given, the date is `1.1.1970`.

Is there a better possibility instead of using regex and parse this by my own?

Comment: if the format is always the same you can use `DateTime.TryParse(...)`

Comment: It is unclear your context. What kinds of strings you are trying to parse? Do you have also legitimate strings with the date part? Otherwise it is easy to detect if you have a string with only 5 chars

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the value as `TimeSpan` and then try to parse it as `DateTime`.

```
var data = "15:00";
if (TimeSpan.TryParse(data, out var time))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}", time);
}
else if (DateTime.TryParse(data, out var datetime))
{
    Console.WriteLine("DateTime: {0}", datetime);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("I don't know how to parse {0}", data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a string like "15:00" and I parse this to DateTime ot
>   DateTimeOffset, the date is set to today.

This is by design.

From [`DateTime.Parse` doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> A string with a time but no date component. The method assumes the
>   **current date** unless you call the `Parse(String, IFormatProvider,
>   DateTimeStyles)` overload and include
>   `DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault` in the styles argument, in which
>   case the method assumes a date of January 1, 0001.

From [`DateTimeOffset.Parse` doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> If  is missing, its default value is the **current day**.

So, for `DateTime`, if you don't use any `DateTimeStyles`, you get the current date

```
var hours = "15:00";
var date = DateTime.Parse(hours, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // 12/9/2018 3:00:00 PM
```

but if you use `DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault` as a third parameter;

```
var hours = "15:00";
var date = DateTime.Parse(hours, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
// 1/1/0001 3:00:00 PM
```

But I think your problem keeps on that sentence; "if the date part is given or not.." How did you decide your string has date part or not? Is it always have 5 characters as [Steve commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693112/c-sharp-parse-datetime-without-date#comment94241693_53693112)? It can be in a format like `4:00`? What about `4:1`? If it can be like `4:1`, it should be parsed as `4:10` or `4:01`?

So, you need to decide first what is the meaning of "if the date part is given or not.." for your case. Then you can easily parse your string to `TimeSpan`, *not* `DateTime` in my opinion, so, you can add it created manually "1.1.1970" with `DateTime(int, int, int)` constructor.

```
if(YourConditionForYourStringNotIncludingDatePart)
{
    var time = TimeSpan.Parse("15:00");
    var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    var result = date.Add(time);
}
```

Using regular expressins for DateTime parsing is *usually* a bad idea. I wouldn't suggest to use it unless you have no other way to do it for DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

I think for that case you could things keep simple. This could be a solution that not depends on the lenght when there is only a timepart:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(ParseWithDummyIfDateAbsent("15:00", new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)));
    Console.WriteLine(ParseWithDummyIfDateAbsent("15:00:22", new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)));
    Console.WriteLine(ParseWithDummyIfDateAbsent("09.12.2018 15:00", new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)));
}

DateTime ParseWithDummyIfDateAbsent(string input, DateTime dummyDate)
{

    if(TimeSpan.TryParse(input, out var timeSpan))
        input = $"{dummyDate.Date.ToShortDateString()} {input}";
    return DateTime.Parse(input);
}
```

Output:

```
01.01.1970 15:00:00
01.01.1970 15:00:22
09.12.2018 15:00:00
```

Depends on your localization:-)